# List Row not updated with use of Dialog

Tags: android, onitemlongclicklistener

I use this code to set OnItemLongClickListener in DiaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter class of my file:

```
ListView list = getListView();
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext()).show();

                return true;       
            }
        });
```

then I use EditListItemDialog to update the rows:

```
package com.example.classorganizer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

class EditListItemDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

private View editText;


  //  public EditListItemDialog(Context context, List<String> fragment_monday) {     //first constructor
  //      super(context);
  //      this.fragment_monday = fragment_monday;
  //  }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_dialog);//here is your xml with EditText and 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons
    View btnOk = findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private List<String> fragment_monday;


public EditListItemDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.fragment_monday = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    fragment_monday.add(((TextView) v).getText().toString());//here is your updated(or not updated) text
    dismiss();
}
}
```

Although everything looks fine, I can't update the row. Dialog works and after clicking the button no changes are made.
Any idea why this may happen?

Edit:

code for Monday file that holds the list:

```
package com.example.classorganizer;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cookbook.data.Constants;
import com.cookbook.data.MyDB;




public class Monday extends ListActivity {



private static final int MyMenu = 0;
MyDB dba;
DiaryAdapter myAdapter;

private class MyDiary{
    public MyDiary(String t, String c){
        title=t;
        content=c;



}

    public String title;
    public String content;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dba = new MyDB(this);
    dba.open();
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_monday);





    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(this);
    this.setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}



private class DiaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<MyDiary> fragment_monday;
    public DiaryAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        fragment_monday = new ArrayList<MyDiary>();
        getdata();

        ListView list = getListView();
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext()).show();

                return true;       
            }
        });

    }

    public void getdata(){
        Cursor c = dba.getdiaries();
        startManagingCursor(c);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String title =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.TITLE_NAME));
                String content =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONTENT_NAME));

                MyDiary temp = new MyDiary(title,content);
                fragment_monday.add(temp);
            } while(c.moveToNext());
        }

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {return fragment_monday.size();}
    public MyDiary getItem(int i) {return fragment_monday.get(i);}
    public long getItemId(int i) {return i;}
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        View v = arg1;
        if ((v == null) || (v.getTag() == null)) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.diaryrow,  null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.mdiary = getItem(arg0);
        holder.mTitle.setText(holder.mdiary.title);


        v.setTag(holder);

        return v;


    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        MyDiary mdiary;
        TextView mTitle;


    }

}




/** Called when the user clicks the Edit button */
public void visitDiary(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Diary.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
/** Called when the user clicks the back button */
public void visitSchedule(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayScheduleScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


}
```

Comment: If its a listview, don't you have to notify the adapter that the data has changed? With something like: notifyDataChanged() or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` for update the listView.

**EDITED:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

class EditListItemDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

private View editText;
private DiaryAdapter adapter;
private int position;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_dialog);//here is your xml with EditText and 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons
    View btnOk = findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);

}


public EditListItemDialog(Context context, DiaryAdapter adapter, int position) {
    super(context);
    this.adapter = adapter;
    this.position = position
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    adapter.getItem(this.position).title = "whatever";
    adapter.getItem(this.position).content = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    dismiss();
}
}
```

Comment: in your onClick(View view) after the  fragment_monday.add(...)

Comment: which adapter did u set? when you add listView.setadapter(adapter)

Comment: If you want post the entire code, I will modify it for you.

Comment: I don't follow, I am sorry but I am very new to it.

Comment: I already posted full EditListItemDialog, which code do you need?

Comment: I posted the code for file with onItemLongClick Listener setup

Comment: I edited the constructor of the class EditListItemDialog for pass the adapter. I dont understand what are you doing with the dialog, because if you want to modify a element of a listView you have to access to it for example from adapter.getItem(position) or something like that.

Comment: new code complains where are DiaryAdapter and adapter. They cannot be resolved to a type...

Comment: import they if you are using eclipse use ctrl+shift+o

Comment: also, in other file with OnItemLongClick Listener error pops up like this : The constructor EditListItemDialog(Context, DiaryAdapter) refers to the missing type DiaryAdapter

Comment: Set DiaryAdapter class as public

Comment: in Monday file you mean, that one that extends BaseAdapter

Comment: `private class DiaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter` as `public class DiaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter`

Comment: I managed to do import, but in Monday file this error remains: The constructor EditListItemDialog(Context) is undefined

Comment: I managed to get rid of the error in Monday file by updating line new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext()).show(); to new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext(), myAdapter).show(); . Dialog opens but data is still not being updated after click button

Comment: can you explain in detail what you wrote here please:  if you want to modify a element of a listView you have to access to it for example from adapter.getItem(position)

Comment: when you manage onclick you didnt change anything of listView. I will rewrite your EditListItemDialog and look the changes. :)

Comment: You have to change the constructor in MOnday class as `new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext(),adapter,position)` remember that you can pass everything that you need to the constructor. Hope it will helps you.

Comment: complains at adapter: adapter cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext(),myAdapter,position)

Comment: please read the code and understand it dont just copy and paste.

Comment: now it complains at full line : The constructor EditListItemDialog(Context, Monday.DiaryAdapter, int) is undefined